# Inserting missing records from Oracle DB into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

I have an Oracle database with a table `Customers` to which I only have read-only access. I would like to copy some columns from this table and insert them into a SQL Server 2008 R2 table called `Customers`, only when the ID does not exist in the destination table.

I'm new to C#.... I can open and read from Oracle successfully using `Oracle.DataAccess` and I can write to SQL Server, but I am lost on how to read from Oracle then write into SQL Server. All the examples I could find are for databases of the same type.

Comment: create two connections: one to an oracle DB, another to a MSSQL DB. alternatively if this is a one time thing, create a linked server in MSSQL...and simply write a query

Comment: Not a one time thing, I have a connection to each DB, the question is how to first compare results to find the id's that need copying and then how to copy into memory to write back to SQL? I am probably missing a concept here. In SQL alone I'd do a join and insert into, but since two DB's from different sources, I don't know where to start.

Comment: If the source tables aren't too large, an option is to use the Import Export Wizard in SQL Management Studio to copy the entire table and then some tsql to insert the missing rows. This uses SSIS behind the scenes, which is the ideal tool for this job.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to follow up on this to share that despite many creative solutions offered here and elsewhere, there was not an efficient enough way to accomplish this task. In most every case, I would have to read the entire contents of two very large tables and then check for missing records without the performance advantage of a true join. I decided to go with a hybrid model where the app obtains basic information from the main `Oracle` database and then reads and writes the supplemental information in and out of `SQL Server`.